# Как переопределить файл стилей из дочерней темы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не получается переопределить файл стилей, который подключается в основной теме.
В дочерней теме пытаюсь переопределить так:

```
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_dequeue_style('new-css');
    wp_deregister_style('new-css');
    wp_enqueue_style('new-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-css.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method' );
```

но подключается стиль из основной темы.
Как это правильно сделать?
В основной теме стиль подключается так:

```
wp_enqueue_style('new-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/new-css.css');
```

в хуке `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'new-css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'new-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/new-css.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method', 0 );
```

Обратите внимание на приоритет 0 (меньше стандартного 10) и на то, что uri дочерней темы - это `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, не `template`.